# How to call a controller method after submitting the button?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, model-view-controller

I was reading about `helper class` in rails but didn't get any clue on implementing it. I have a button on views page:

```
 <tbody>
   <% @book.each do |book| %>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3"><%= link_to 'Show page numbers', book, :class => 'btn btn-info' %></td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
```

Aim:

1. click on button and fetch the page number from controller
2. replace the button with fetched `page numbers`

I have a method defined in `controller` class:

```
def fetch_page_numbers
...
end
```

My Questions:

- How to call `fetch_page_numbers` method from view
- After retrieving the result from database How to show the number instead of buttons in view
- How to apply `redirect_to` in `fetch_page_numbers` because till I never redirect the data to same page

Any hint upon it? Thanks for your time

Answer (score 1):

1. *How to call `fetch_page_numbers` method from view:*

   You need to bind this action to a route in your `routes.rb` file, then call that route or the generated helper - [guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)
2. *After retrieving the result from database How to show the number instead of buttons in view*

   If you want to dynamically replace your button, you need to use an AJAX request, and handle its response in javascript - entirely different subject, try [this](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html)
3. *How to apply `redirect_to` in `fetch_page_numbers` because till I never redirect the data to same page*

   You can't use rails' `redirect_to` with AJAX, what you can do is e.g. include an `redirect_path` key in your response, then redirect there via javascript. But I think what you ment is something like `render json: {..data..}`

All in all, are you sure you approached your problem correctly? None of your questions have anything to do with any helper class, and dynamically replacing a button is a bit contradictory with redirecting.

Always try to split your problem into smallest parts possible. Try following the MVP (Minimum Viable Product) ideology - create something easy, but working, then add small features.

If you do that, all your current questions are answered by the rails [guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/index.html). Good luck!